# Limit in the number of columns that can be used in a TSQL transaction

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a stored procedure for inserting new records into my FOLDER table. This sproc uses a function that processes the xml string.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FolderUploader]
@xmlString xml
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    Insert into mydb.dbo.FOLDER
    ...350 columns...
    Select
    ...350 columns...
    from mydb.dbo.myfunction(@xmlString)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)  
        SELECT @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
END CATCH
```

(I know, the columns are sooo many but that's just the way it is. And they've been using this table way before me so I can't just change it.)

My problem is that I get an error when running my sproc:

*The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization. Please simplify the query.*

So I tried temporarily commenting out 300 of the 350 columns. And it worked fine. Is there a limit to the number of columns I can use here? If there is, what is the maximum number of columns I can use? Thanks.

EDIT

Here is the code for myfunction:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[myfunction]
(
    @varXML AS XML
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT Child.value('RECID[1]', 'BIGINT') 'RECID',
    ...the other 349 columns...
    FROM @varXML.nodes('DocumentElement/XMLTable') EMP(Child)
);
```

Comment: You're not at the limit - here's the [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.ASPX) (which you can then adjust for your version, but I'm fairly certain the limits haven't changed much over the years)

Comment: Inserting to a table with 350 columns does not cause this. Dare I ask to see the code for `myfunction`?

Comment: If xml string contains more then one record, you could try to insert less records at once.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hey thanks for that link! If you make that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have foreign keys defined for the 350 columns? There is a recommendation not to have [more than 253 foreign key constraints on one table.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: [The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization" during simple DELETE](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/172561/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-stack-space-during-query-optimization-during-simple-delete)

Comment: @athabaska I was only trying to insert 9 records tho

Comment: @MikaelEriksson nope, not even one foreign key actually. Maybe it's the xml that has a problem. I don't have xml indexes tho. Is there a limit to the number of child nodes per parent node? B/c I use 350 child nodes in myfunction.

Comment: What version/build number are you using of SQL Server? `select @@version`

Comment: Here: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86)   Jul  9 2008 14:43:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6001: Service Pack 1) `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35323/discussion-between-artemis-and-mikael-eriksson)